# List content into Ruby variable

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to use binding.pry to access objects and variables within object. I tried this:

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::WechatRequestBuilder::Submit>)> request_builder
=> #<WechatRequestBuilder:0x007fba3f1a7560 @env="test_env", @request_modifier=#<RequestModifier:0x007fba3f1a7510>>
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::WechatRequestBuilder::Submit>)> WechatRequestBuilder:0x007fba3f1a7560
SyntaxError: unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::WechatRequestBuilder::Submit>)>
```

How I can list the content of WechatRequestBuilder:0x007fba3f1a7560 and see all variables?

What should I create `expect` statement? Probably: `expect(request_builder.WechatRequestBuilder).to receive(anything)`

Answer (score 0):

`request_builder` is already an instance you want to examine. Here is how:

```
▶ class Foo
▷   attr_reader :foo, :bar
▷   def initialize(foo:, bar:)
▷     @foo = foo
▷     @bar = bar
▷   end  
▷ end  
▶ foo = Foo.new(foo: 42, bar: :foo)
#⇒ #<Foo:0x00564c1db7bed8 @bar=:foo, @foo=42>
▶ foo.instance_variables
#⇒ [:@foo, :@bar]
▶ foo.instance_variables.map { |v| [v, foo.instance_variable_get(v)] }.to_h
#⇒ {:@foo=>42, :@bar=>:foo}
```